# Make Slider autoscroll images automatically with js or css or both

Tags: javascript, css, ratchet

I am using the Slider from Ratchet css, which as far as I know does nothing as far as auto scrolling goes.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="slider" id="mySlider">
  <div class="slide-group">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="/assets/img/slide-1.jpg">
      <span class="slide-text">
        <span class="icon icon-left-nav"></span>
        Slide me
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="/assets/img/slide-2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="/assets/img/slide-3.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is either with js or css or both have the images scrolling every few seconds.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the sliders.js it is based off

https://github.com/thebird/Swipe

So a function like this could work, it might need some tweaking.

```
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
  startSlide: 2,
  speed: 400,
  auto: 3000,
  continuous: true,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});
```

Comment: I AM, referencing ratched.js but it doesn't auto scroll the images

Comment: Could you provide the full html file, so we can have a better understanding of what is going wrong or is missing.

Comment: That was all the html provided that relates to the slider. See here: http://goratchet.com/components/

Comment: That slider is one that will require you to slide your finder over the screen, it will not auto scroll, you would have to bind an event to it like in the sliders.js piece of the documentation

Comment: I just though with javascript there would be a way to get the code above to scroll the images without having to include any extra libraries